# List all purgeable files in macOS Sierra

Tags: macos, storage, disk-space

I disabled macOS Sierra storage optimizations and the Storage tab in About this Mac still shows over 70 GB as purgeable space. Is there a utility to display which files are considered as purgeable?

Comment: Although it doesn't answer the question, connecting to your backup drive(s) may help to resolve this issue.  https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT204015  See also my answer to my own related question https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/361011/80135  My experience suggests that you have to back up to *all* of the drives that Time Machine knows about before it clears out local snapshots.

Comment: Again not answering the question. I would use Disk Inventory X to get a better idea of where you should focus your attention. http://www.derlien.com/  I would look at IOS updates and not needed backups as they tend to take up quite a bit of space usually.

Answer (score 1):

Two utilities that show and optimise purgable space are DaisyDisk and CleanMyMac X.  My experience is that these utilities will clear 20-30% of the space that it reports as purgable.